# Direct self-reference leading to cycle exception

Tags: java, serialization, elasticsearch, jackson, deserialization

I have a class; something like the following:

```
public abstract class ElasticSearchValue<T> {

  private Long txId;
  private Long currentTxId;
  private T previous;

  public Long getTxId() {
    return txId;
  }

  public void setTxId(Long txId) {
    this.txId = txId;
  }

  public Long getCurrentTxId() {
    return currentTxId;
  }

  public void setCurrentTxId(Long currentTxId) {
    this.currentTxId = currentTxId;
  }

  public Object getPrevious() {
    return previous;
  }

  public void setPrevious(T previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
  }

}
```

And a class that extends the class above

```
public class DailyActivity extends ElasticSearchValue<DailyActivity> {

  Long agentId;
  Date date;
  Long success;

  public Long getAgentId() {
    return agentId;
  }

  public void setAgentId(Long agentId) {
    this.agentId = agentId;
  }

  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }

  public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }

  public Long getSuccess() {
    return success;
  }

  public void setSuccess(Long success) {
    this.success = success;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return agentId + "_" + date.toString();
  }

}
```

Now, I have an object of type `DailyActivity`, and when I try to convert it into a JSON string, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain:
>   com.pr.analysis.DailyActivity["previous"])

I have looked for solution on google but the solution which I get asks to put `jsonIgnore` to previous value which is not what I intent to do. Has anyone faced the same issue? 
Thanks

**EDIT**
I know there is a cycle in the class and I am asking how to deserialize the class which has a self reference?

Answer (score 18):

In this case you need to annotate the relationships with [@JsonManagedReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonManagedReference.html) and [@JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonBackReference.html) like this:

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 @JsonBackReference
 private Company company
```

And

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
 @JsonManagedReference
 private Set<Employee> employee = new HashSet<Employee>();
```

There is a nice example [here](http://keenformatics.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion.html)

Answer (score 13):

`SerializationFeature` has a property called `FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES` default is `true` but you can set to `false` to skip this kind of exception.

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES, false);
```

If you are using SpringBoot you can simply add `spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-self-references=false`
 in your `application.properties`

Comment: Warning: Using this solution code might go into Infinite recursion. e.g.Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion(StackOverflowError)

Comment: This most probably would cause as stated by @KiranBhagwat

Answer (score 8):

The self-reference is here:

```
public class DailyActivity extends ElasticSearchValue<DailyActivity> {
```

You're saying `DailyActivity` is an `ElasticSearchValue<DailyActivity>`, which is by itself an `ElasticSearchValue<ElasticSearchValue<DailyActivity>>`, and this goes on infinitely...

**Update:** I would break that in two classes. Create `DailyActivity` without subclassing `ElasticSearchValue`:

```
public class DailyActivity {
  // the same content as your class above
```

then create another class like:

```
public class ElacticDailyActivity extends ElasticSearchValue<DailyActivity> {
```

Comment: Ya, I know that and am asking how to deserialize such a class?

Answer (score 3):

Try `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation as given in this example. More details here http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Identifiable
{
    public int value;

    public Identifiable next;
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I have configured my project as mentioned in above link, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to related question and a sensible way of handling this in my opinion.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65920426/12594701

In current case it would help to annotate 'previous' like below

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"previous"})//... along with other annotations
private T previous;
```

Answer (score -9):

I guess somewhere in your code. The previous of some instance of DailyActivity point to itself.

Comment: Ya, it obviously does. Let me re-frame the question how can you deserialize an object which has a self reference?

Comment: I don't think you can. I will set the previous to null when it points to itself before send the object. In other end, after recevied the  object, change the previous to itself if it's null. Maybe someone else have better idea.