# Java Object to JSON: Ignore Cycle

Tags: java, json, serialization

I've got an entity with the following signature:

```
public class Record extends BaseEntity<Long, Record> {...}
```

Now I want to send it via REST using JSON. Problem is, the self reference. Because of that I get the following error.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct
>   self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain:
>   Record["this"])

What can I do, e.g. which annotation, to convert this object to JSON?

Comment: Could you share your BaseEntity and Record class?

Comment: Sorry, not possible, to many internal features of my company and it is way to big (> 300 lines of code)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218568/direct-self-reference-leading-to-cycle-exception

Comment: @LStrike: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonIgnore` annotation in your `BaseEntity class` above the generic instance variable which is referring to record class. It  ignore one of the sides of the relationship, thus breaking the chain.

Alternatively, you can use `@JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)