# Direct self-reference leading to cycle

Tags: java, jersey

I'm trying to send a request to get back an array of an object - `Coupon` when I submit the request I get the answer-

> Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain:
>   `java.util.HashSet[0]` => `model.Coupon["emptyCoupon"]` => `model.Coupon["emptyCoupon"]`)

The `model.Coupon` probably does the problem.
empty coupon is intended to be returned if the requested coupon does not exist.

```
public static final int NO_ID = -1;

private static final Coupon EMPTY_COUPON = new Coupon(NO_ID, null, null, null, NO_ID, NO_ID, null, NO_ID, null);

private long id = NO_ID;
private String title;
private LocalDate startDate;
private LocalDate endDate;
private int amount;
private int category;
private String message;
private double price;
private String image;

public Coupon() {
}

private Coupon(long id, String title, LocalDate start_date, LocalDate end_date, int amount, int category,
        String message, double price, String image) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.startDate = start_date;
    this.endDate = end_date;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.category = category;
    this.message = message;
    this.price = price;
    this.image = image;
}

public Coupon getEmptyCoupon() {
    return EMPTY_COUPON;
}
```

Before I added the `EMPTY_COUPON` I had no problems with the requests.
I want the emptyCoupon in the code, and I'll be happy to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Direct self-reference leading to cycle exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218568/direct-self-reference-leading-to-cycle-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are serializing to JSON or XML with Jersey, you may not have cycles in your object graph.

Jersey doesn't have a `@JsonBackReference` like Jackson does, so you might consider to move the `EMPTY_COUPON` in a separate class (something like `Constants.java`) and obtain it from there.

Other options are to add `@XmlIgnore` to your field or to switch to another JSON serializer like Jackson.